# Use the scene browser thumbnails

Tags: python

We are working on an asset manager in a preview, like this.

[image]

And we could add a choise to not use calculated thumbnails or custom thumbnails via a path.

If we choose nor Calculated nor thumbnails path, we want to have the thumbnails browser result.

[image]

Like that we could see the result of the import in the library and change it later.

So, is there a way in python to use this image and save it ?